# Welches oder Welche

Tags: grammar-identification, pronoun, demonstrative-pronoun, interrogative

Diesen Satz habe ich im Kursbuch des Niveaus B2 (Menschen) gefunden:

> Welches sind die Hauptgründe für Ihre Mitgliedschaft in einem oder mehreren privaten sozialen Netzwerken?

Das Wort "Hauptgründe" ist plural. Warum steht "Welches" da statt "Welche"?

Answer (score 3):

Der Grund dafür wird leider in vielen Quellen übersehen, auch in dem sonst von mir sehr geschätzten Wiktionary. Dort steht beim Wort [welches](https://de.wiktionary.org/wiki/welches) zwar völlig richtig, dass es eine Form des Demonstrativpronomens [welcher](https://de.wiktionary.org/wiki/welcher) ist, aber es fehlt eine wichtige Information, auf die ich in wenigen Zeilen eingehe.

Die grammatischen Kontexte, in denen das Wort "welches" gemäß diesem Wiktionary-Eintrag auftreten kann, sind folgende (Beispiele von mir):

- Genitiv Singular Maskulinum

  > Welches Mannes Idee war das?
- Nominativ Singular Neutrum

  > Welches Kind war hier?
- Genitiv Singular Neutrum

  > Welches Kindes Idee war das?
- Akkusativ Singular Neutrum

  > Welches Kind siehst du?

(Bei den beiden Genitiv-Formen kann man stattdessen auch "welchen" verwenden)

Aber:

> falsch: Welches Gründe sind das?
> richtig: Welche Gründe sind das?

---

Kommen wir nun zu dem, was nicht in Wiktionary steht. Sehen wir uns zu diesem Zweck zunächst diese Sätze an:

> Dies sind die Gründe.
> Das sind die Gründe.

Die beiden Wörter *»dies«* und *»das«* sind Demonstrativpronomen. Sie treten in ihrem jeweiligen Satz als eigenständiges Substantiv auf. Man nennt das dann *»Subjektpronomen«.* Das Verb *»sind«* ist eine Form des Kopulaverbs *»sein«* und *»die Gründe«* ist ein Teil des Prädikats, nämlich ein Gleichsetzungsnominativ. Insbesondere sind *»dies«* und *»das«* keine Bestandteile der Nominalgruppe, dessen Kern das Substantiv *»Gründe«* ist. (Diese Nominalgruppe besteht nur aus dem Artikel *»die«* und eben dem Kern der Gruppe, dem Substantiv *»Gründe«*.)

In allen zuvor genannten Beispielen, in denen das Wort *»welches«* verwendet wurde, ist dieses Wort aber ein Bestandteil einer Nominalgruppe, und es übernimmt in dieser Nominalgruppe die Rolle des Determinativs (des Bestimmers oder *»Artikelworts«*) Determinative sind oftmals Artikel, können aber auch Pronomen und andere Wörter sein.

Wenn eine Form von *»welcher«* innerhalb einer Nominalgruppe als Determinativ eines Substantivs verwendet wird, dann stimmt alles, was in Wiktionary steht. Aber es kann eben auch allein, als eigenständiges Subjektpronomen existieren, und dann kann es auch im Plural in der Form *»welches«* erscheinen:

> Welches sind die Gründe?

Aber (siehe oben):

> Welche Gründe sind das?